# How to create own Symfony Assetic Filters?

Tags: php, symfony1, assetic

I would like to create my own Assetic filter similar to those LESS, SASS and Google Closure Compiler filters.

I can see that the filters are in `vendor/assetic/src/Assetic/Filter`, but obviously I can't just modify that codebase.

Comment: Why can't you just modify the codebase? Fork it and go on.

Comment: I rather not touch the codebase.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The right way should be to create a service that encapsulate your business logic inside the DIC and to tag it with the **assetic.filter_manager** tag.

For example the builtin coffee script filter is registered this way:

```
<service id="assetic.filter.coffee" class="%assetic.filter.coffee.class%">
    <tag name="assetic.filter" alias="coffee" />
    <argument>%assetic.filter.coffee.bin%</argument>
    <argument>%assetic.filter.coffee.node%</argument>
</service>
```

Modifying the code base is definitely the wrong way to do something like this, symfony DIC provide much better solutions!

Comment: No, it's not about modifying the codebase and this one actually works.

Comment: This is NOT modifying the code base. This is the correct answer ten times over.